# Possible to cache RMarkdown results with GHA?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, github-actions

I'm using GitHub Actions to render some RMarkdown files and deploy them to a website, using `rmarkdown::render_site()`.

But some of them have some long-running code. When running locally, I can use *knitr*'s caching to reduce runtime between different runs:

````
```{r, cache=TRUE}
# long running code
```
````

But when using GHA, the cache results are not maintained between different runs. I was wondering whether there is a way around this, to reduce running time between different workflow runs?

I know about caching R package installations (as shown [here](https://github.com/r-lib/actions/tree/master/examples#standard-ci-workflow) for example). Is something similar possible for *knitr* caches?

Comment: I think this is possible – if you can tell me a couple of things, I can help you write out this workflow: 1) what's the write location for knitr on the Ubuntu workflow runner? 2) what would you use for the cache key? Perhaps the RMarkdown files themselves? 3) can you add a link to the GH Actions workflow if it's public, or a minimal reproducible example (make a new repo with a few test files and workflows) if your actual one is private?

Comment: Hi @jidicula, thanks for your comment! I took a first shot at implementing this in this minimal example with just a single Rmd: https://github.com/milanmlft/Rmd-website/blob/c9cad5f01634174c4933a6b5b19e1d263a811495/.github/workflows/render.yml#L48-L53. This works but is probably too naive. For example, the cache key is fixed so will not get updated if anything changes. An additional difficulty is that, ultimately, I would like this to work for multiple Rmd files, where each one has its own cache. Thanks a lot for any help!